# Json Decoded data unable to convert in string format

Tags: android, json, flutter, flutter-layout, jsonparser

```
[ {
    banner_image: banner5.jpeg
  }, {
    banner_image: banner4.jpeg
  }, {
    banner_image: banner3.jpeg
  }, {
    banner_image: banner2.jpeg
  }, {
    banner_image: banner1.jpeg
  }, 
]
```

I have fetched this data from json url and i just want the .jpeg values in string format

Comment: can you share full code

Comment: This is not a valid json. The file names must be in quotes. Otherwise you must parse the file line by line and extract the file names and put them within quotes and create a valid json, which you can process with your json parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope these codes help.

```
  List<String> imageList=[]
http.Response? response;
      response = await api.getRequest(apiUrl2,
          "YOUR-API-URL");
      if (response != null && response.statusCode == 200) {
        List<String> apiResponse = <String>[];
        List<dynamic>? values = json.decode(response.body);
        if (values != null) {
          for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (values[i] != null) {
              Map<String, String> map = values[i];
              imageList.add(map.Value);
            }
          }
        }
        return imageList;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your json to list of string then use it seperatly

List stringList = (jsonDecode(input) as List).cast();

String strBanner1 = stringList[0];
String strBanner2 = stringList[1];
.
.
.